# The act of getting a manicure?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, conjugación

I know that the person who does your nails is a "manicurista" but I don't know the conjugation for getting a manicure. For example, if I was offering to pay for my wife's manicure, I would say, "would you like to get a manicure" or "would you like to get your nails done". But I don't know the same conjugation to ask that question in Spanish.

Comment: The term _manicurista_ is a valid term in Spanish, but is used only in the following countries ([according to the RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ODM1JT0)): Colombia, Ecuador, El Salvador, Honduras, Mexico, Panama, Peru, Puerto Rico, Dominican Republic and Venezuela. In other contries we use _manicuro_ or _manicura_, You have to check that the translation you seek is adapted to your region, as some terms or expressions may vary.

Answer (score 4):

In short, you would use ***hacerse*** [las uñas/la manicura] as an auxiliary verb, pretty much in the same way you use the verb to get.

To complement Gorpik's and Ustanak's answers, I'd like to add a couple of ideas:

1. Spanish is *slower* than English to make verbs from nouns, (especially neologisms), and [the reason](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/08/meddling-with-nouns-whos-medalling-now/) seems to be the need for verb endings that imply the creation of additional neologisms rather than giving new meanings to the exisiting ones: it just [does not sound right](http://navioenlinea.bligoo.cl/neologismos-tecnologicos-y-el-idioma-espanol#.V2vd6qIl_Kg) —at least at first—. While in English there is the verb [*to manicure*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manicure), in Spanish the best (and only?) choice is to add an auxiliary verb to the noun.
2. Unsurprisingly —for foreign words—, both the noun and its gender change depending on the region, hence you have:

   - *Hacerse la manicura* in **Spain**. (Thanks CarlosAlejo)
   - *Hacerse la* manicure in **Chile**. Pronounced [ma.ni'cjur]: the closest one can get to the French pronunciation with Spanish phonetics, I think.
   - *Hacerse el* manicure in **Colombia**. (Thanks Nicholas J.)

Comment: ¿Será así de _lento_ el castellano incorporando palabras porque todo debe "pasar" por la RAE?

Comment: Sin duda que influye: a diferencia del inglés, existe una autoridad central que (todavía) goza de cierta reputación y respeto.

Comment: No creo, la gente no pide permiso a la RAE para usar las palabras. Seguro que algo influye, pero tiene que haber algo más relacionado con la propia estructura del lenguaje.

Answer (score 3):

We have no specific verb for that in Spanish; we'd rather use *hacer la manicura*. Both your English options have an easy translation:

> Would you like to get a manicure? --> ¿Quieres que te hagan la manicura?
>
> Would you like to get your nails done? --> ¿Quieres que te hagan las uñas?

Notice that in Spanish we tend to use the passive form less than in English. These are good examples where we would use an active impersonal construction rather than the English passive.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no expression to verbalise *manicure*.

The way of asking this, will regionally depend on how people refer to the action.

> ¿Te gustaría que se te *adornen/pinten* las uñas?

Comment: I agree, I couldn't think of one either, hence the question. The natural conjugation would be "manicurio" (???) but I've never heard that term used at all before, just doesn't sound right.

Comment: @JimBeam That doesn't make sense. We know *manicure* is a noun, but at least, I would never say *voy a manicurar tus uñas*.

Comment: In Chile we also use *hacerse la* manicure (pronounced [ma.ni'cjur], approaching the French term). You don't convert the noun to a verb, but add an auxiliary verb instead.

Comment: I agree with @Rafael, however, here in Colombia, we say *hacerse el* manicure.

Comment: @Rafael In Spain we say _hacerse la manicura_, we don't use the French term, we use an adapted version. To answer the question, we would say _**¿Te gustaría hacerte la manicura?**_ or even _**¿Te gustaría hacerte una manicura?**_

Comment: @Rafael You should submit that as an answer (and maybe add the comments from NicholasJ and CarlosAlejo about how the expression changes in other countries)

Comment: I'm agree with @CarlosAlejo and, for me, the same sentences with **hacerse las uñas** are also correct.

Comment: @JulioCodesal agreed.

Comment: @Yay done! I almost forgot to tell